# Distance calculated between one row of array 1 for every row of array 2 then move on to next row of array 1 and repeat

Tags: matlab, gps, distance

I am trying to find out the distance between two list of locations(lat,long). 
I have them all stored in separate arrays lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2. The first set is the ones I am reading of a gps system and the second is a reference. They both have over 1000 rows.

What I want to do is.
Calculate distance between lat1, lon1 for all points of lat2, lon2
Then move to 2nd row of lat1, lon1 again calculate for all rows of lat2, lon2
and keep repeating.

So every calculation of the lat1, lon1 should be performed for every point of lat2, lon2.

I have to finally take a decision based on the output distance being <4

Could someone help with this please. Really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have the stats toolbox because then you can just use `pdist2` for this:

```
pdist2([lat1, lon1], [lat2, lon2])
```

If you don't have the stats toolbox:

```
%// Simple example data
a = [0, 0; 0, 1; 1, 1];
b = [0, 0; 0, 1; 1, 1];

n = size(a,1);

[X, Y] = ndgrid(1:n,1:n)
dist = sqrt(sum((a(X(:),:) - b(Y(:),:)).^ 2, 2))

reshape(dist, n, n)
```

results (correctly) in:

```
ans =

   0.00000   1.00000   1.41421
   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000
   1.41421   1.00000   0.00000
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back so quickly. Actually I don't have the stat toolbox. Is there any other way of getting around it?

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very very helpful...been struggling with this for so long. Thank you!